# Can you build apt package manager from Cygwin

Tags: github, debian, cygwin, open-source, apt

I saw lots of questions about apt alternatives for Cygwin but i wonder can you build it yourself.

Can't you just download the source code and run

```
cmake <path_to_source>
```

Just like Debian stated in the apt source code in github

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: My Cygwin version is old and when i try to build cmake(i needed the newest version) it says that there is no c++ compiler that can use some flags(i can't remember)